# Do principal moments of inertia remain unchanged under different principal axes?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, moment-of-inertia

Attached at the end of this question are an excerpt of a textbook which proved existence of principal axes. However, the principal axes may not be unique; actually the text assumes in a later section when deriving Euler's equations of motion that the principal axes is not fixed in the body in general. So my question is: Does principal moments of inertia remain unchanged under different principal axes? I guess so because when differentiating the angular momentum which is a product of principal moment and angular velocity in the derivation of Euler's equations of motion, only angular velocity is differentiated while the principal moment acts as a constant coefficient. Thank you for help me clarify this issue.

[image]

Comment: It is really useful to notice that this problem, the general elastic vibration problem, quantum mechanics and many other linear problems in physics are all linear eigenvalue problems which means that the special cases that appear in one also appear in the others. You are interested in situations where you have some choice of eigenvectors $v'_{1,2} = \cos\theta v_1 \pm \sin\theta v_2$ and your question is about the eigenvalues associated with the chosen vectors. If you already know QM or the general elastic vibration (or abstract linear algebra) problem then you know the answer.

Comment: Thanks but, my major is not physics, theoretic or engineering, and I'm not going to go as deep into this subject as a physics or mechanics phd student has to. So I have no idea what you are talking about and I believe there are some more accessible ways to answer my question. For example, a simple "yes" would suffice.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "different principal axes". The principal axes of a body _are fixed to the body_ and do not change w.r.t. the body orientation. A cylinder has a principal axis along its length, regardless of which way it is pointing. So how do you propose to change the axes?

Comment: @ja72 With sufficient symmetry there is a degenerate subspace. Consider a unform right circular cylinder...

Comment: Please check this out
http://stemandmusic.in/physics/moiNotes.php Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

For a rigid body, the principle moments (and thereby the entire inertia tensor) are constant. They would only change if the geometry of the body changed, which, assuming this is a rigid system, the geometry does not.

As a body changes orientation (i.e. rotates), while those 2nd moments of inertia remain constant from the perspective of the body itself, they point in different directions in absolute nonrotating space (the axes point along different vector lines of action). Therefore, an observer not rotating with the body sees changes to the inertia tensor, although those changes are restricted, since the tensor is not really changing but just rotating. This is what the $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ equation in the image you posted actually is saying.

As the other answer says, angular momentum is given by:

$$
\vec{L} =  I \cdot \vec{\omega}
$$

so the derivative of angular momentum, which as you might know is the torque in an inertial frame, is given by

$$
\frac{d\vec{L}}{dt} = \frac{dI}{dt}\cdot\vec{\omega}+I\cdot\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt}
$$

This is what the "stationary" (more accurately, "nonrotating") observer sees in a torque equation. In the case of that observer, the inertia tensor $I$ varies with time and so the full product rule for derivatives is necessary as written above. However, the derivative of $I$ is not completely general, but is a known function of the rotation rate of the body ($\vec{\omega}$ itself) and the updated $I$ at any time is then a function of the absolute body orientation (rotation). Note that the total rotation of the body is, roughly speaking, the integral of angular velocity $\vec{\omega}$, although it is a bit more complicated with rotations than with linear displacements.

In a general elastic body, the inertia tensor can change on the body as well, but in that case the changes in the body frame will be limited by the stress and strain relations. I highly doubt that is what your book is talking about. Your book is probably talking about a rotating rigid body from the perspective of a nonrotating observer, but I would have to see the other page to know.

Answer (score 0):

Say a body with 3×3 orientation matrix ${\rm R}(t)$ rotates with angular velocity ${\boldsymbol \omega}$ expressed in an inertial frame.

This body consists of a scalar mass, and a 3×3 symmetric inertia tensor along the body coordinates ${\rm I}_{body}$. If this tensor is diagonal then the orientation represents the direction of the principal axes.

The rotation vector in the body frame is ${\boldsymbol \omega}_{body} = {\rm R}^\top {\boldsymbol \omega}$ and hence the angular momentum vector is the body frame is

$$ {\bf L}_{body} = {\rm I}_{body} {\boldsymbol \omega}_{body}$$ where ${\rm I}_{body}$ contains constant coefficients.

But dynamics is done on inertial frames, and such the above needs to be transformed into:

$$ {\bf L} = {\rm R}{\bf L}_{body} = \underbrace{ \left( {\rm R} {\rm I}_{body}  {\rm R}^\top \right)}_{{\rm I}} {\boldsymbol \omega}$$

Now the 3×3 inertia tensor ${\rm I}$ *is not constant* with time. This reflects that fact that the principal axes ride along the body which is moving.